# Regex pattern matching with various end points

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to extract substring, which has specific pattern, from following string list by javascript.

But I have problem in setting **regex pattern**.

**List of Input String**

1. search?w=tot&DA=YZR&t__nil_searchbox=btn&sug=&o=&`q=%EB%B9%84%EC%BD%98`
2. search?`q=%EB%B9%84%EC%BD%98`&go=%EC%A0…4%EB%B9%84%EC%BD%98&sc=8-2&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=f05407c5bcb9496990d2874135aee8e9
3. where=nexearch&`query=%EB%B9%84%EC%BD%98`&sm=top_hty&fbm=0&ie=utf8

**Expected Pattern Matching Result**

`%EB%B9%84%EC%BD%98` for above cases.

**Regex**

`/(query|q)=.*` + ***ADDITIONAL REGEX HERE*** + `/`

Its end point would be `$` or `first appeared &`

**Question**

What should I write for ***ADDITIONAL REGEX***?

You can test it [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/xG2qS3/1). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the first capturing group to non-capturing group and then add a negated character class instead of `.*`

```
\b(?:query|q)=([^&\n]*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xG2qS3/2)

```
> var s = "where=nexearch& query=%EB%B9%84%EC%BD%98&sm=top_hty&fbm=0&ie=utf8"
undefined
> var pat = /\b(?:query|q)=([^&\n]*)/;
> pat.exec(s)[1]
'%EB%B9%84%EC%BD%98'
```

Comment: This will return the value for any parameter **ending** in `query`, such as `xquery`, which is probably not a good thing.

Comment: add  a word boundary.. Now it won't.

Comment: I cannot really go along with using regexps like this to parse query strings. It's too brittle. To take a contrived example, imagine that my query parameter is named `foo$query`. That's a perfectly valid parameter name. Yet your regexp will pick it up as if it were `query`. You are using the `\b` word boundary with a particular meaning in regexps in a context where word boundaries mean something else. I don't think regexps should be used to parse query strings any more than JS or CSS or HTML or any other "language", and yes, query strings are a sort of little language.

Comment: At a minimum, you should replace the `\b` with `(?:^|&)`. Coincidentally, that would **not** pick up the result in your case, where you have a space before `query`, which actually makes this an invalid query string, in which case not returning anything should be considered correct behavior IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally suggest an alternate approach, using a more-procedural function to match the required parameter-values instead of a 'simple' regular expression. While it may look more complex at first, it does allow for easy extension should you need to find different, or additional, parameter values in future.

That said:

```
/* haystack:
     String, the string in which you're looking for the
     parameter-values,
   needles:
     Array, the parameters whose values you're looking for
*/
function queryGrab(haystack, needles) {
  // creating a regular expression from the array of needles,
  // given an array of ['q','query'], this will result in:
  // /^(q)|(query)/gi
  var reg = new RegExp('^(' + needles.join(')|(') + ')', 'gi'),

    // finding either the index of the '?' character in the haystack:
    queryIndex = haystack.indexOf('?'),

    // getting the substring from the haystack, starting
    // after the '?' character:
    keyValues = haystack.substring(queryIndex + 1)
      // splitting that string on the '&' characters,
      // to form an array:
      .split('&')
      // filtering that array (with Array.prototype.filter()),
      // the 'keyValue' argument is the current array-element
      // from the array over which we're iterating:
      .filter(function(keyValue) {
        // if RegExp.prototype.test() returns true,
        // meaning the supplied string ('keyValue')
        // is matched by the created regular expression,
        // the current element is retained in the filtered
        // array:
        return reg.test(keyValue);
    // converting that filtered-array to a string
    // on the naive assumption each searched-string
    // should return only one match:
    }).toString();

  // returning a substring of the keyValue, from after
  // the position of the '=' character:
  return keyValues.substring(keyValues.indexOf('=') + 1);
}

// essentially irrelevant, just for the purposes of
// providing a demonstration; here we get all the
// elements of class="haystack":
var haystacks = document.querySelectorAll('.haystack'),

  // the parameters we're looking for:
  needles = ['q', 'query'],

  // an 'empty' variable for later use:
  retrieved;

// using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over, and
// perform a function on, each of the .haystack elements
// (using Function.prototype.call() to use the array-like
// NodeList instead of an array):
Array.prototype.forEach.call(haystacks, function(stack) {
  // like filter(), the variable is the current array-element

  // retrieved caches the found parameter-value (using
  // a variable because we're using it twice):
  retrieved = queryGrab(stack.textContent, needles);

  // setting the next-sibling's text:
  stack.nextSibling.nodeValue = '(found: ' + retrieved + ')';

  // updating the HTML of the current node, to allow for
  // highlighting:
  stack.innerHTML = stack.textContent.replace(retrieved, '<span class="found">$&</span>');
});
```

```js
function queryGrab(haystack, needles) {
  var reg = new RegExp('^(' + needles.join(')|(') + ')', 'gi'),
    queryIndex = haystack.indexOf('?'),
    keyValues = haystack.substring(queryIndex + 1)
    .split('&')
    .filter(function(keyValue) {
      return reg.test(keyValue);
    }).toString();
  return keyValues.substring(keyValues.indexOf('=') + 1);
}

var haystacks = document.querySelectorAll('.haystack'),
  needles = ['q', 'query'],
  retrieved;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(haystacks, function(stack) {
  retrieved = queryGrab(stack.textContent, needles);
  stack.nextSibling.nodeValue = '(found: ' + retrieved + ')';
  stack.innerHTML = stack.textContent.replace(retrieved, '<span class="found">$&</span>');
});
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}
.haystack {
  display: block;
  color: #999;
}
.found {
  color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="haystack">search?w=tot&amp;DA=YZR&amp;t__nil_searchbox=btn&amp;sug=&amp;o=&amp;q=%EB%B9%84%EC%BD%98</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="haystack">search?q=%EB%B9%84%EC%BD%98&amp;go=%EC%A0…4%EB%B9%84%EC%BD%98&amp;sc=8-2&amp;sp=-1&amp;sk=&amp;cvid=f05407c5bcb9496990d2874135aee8e9</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="haystack">where=nexearch&amp;query=%EB%B9%84%EC%BD%98&amp;sm=top_hty&amp;fbm=0&amp;ie=utf8</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle (for easier off-site experimentation)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1gur9uue/).

References:

- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`RegExp()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).
- [Regular Expression guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Answer (score 1):

Regexps are not the best way to parse these query strings. There are libraries and tools, but if you want to do it yourself:

```
function parseQueryString(url) {
    return _.object(url .              // build an object from pairs
        split('?')[1]   .              // take the part after the ?
        split('&')      .              // split it by &
        map(function(str) {            // turn parts into 2-elt array
            return str.split('=');     // broken at =
        })
    );
}
```

This uses Underscore's `_.object`, which creates an object from an array of arrays of key/value pairs, but if you don't want to use that, you can write your own equivalent in a couple of lines.

Now the value you are looking for is just

```
params = parseQueryString(url);
return params.q || params.query;
```